# How do I use FileOpenDialog and Image in WinPE using C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winpe

I'm developing an application to run on WinPE.
I use C# and WPF(.Net Framework 4.5)

But I face some problems.

I would like to use select file using `FileOpenDialog`. it is not operated in WinPE(version 6.3)

I tried two way to use `FileOpenDialog`

1. `System.Windows.Forms.FileOpenDialog` - Not happed anything
2. `Microsoft.Win32.FileOpenDialog` - Exception Occurred

Another problem is a `Image`.
I want to use image but some images will not be appeared.

The image has small size under 1KB appear normally. But the image has large size over 400KB do not appear on the screen.

All functions are normally operated on Windows 10 But these problems only appear in WinPE.

How do I solve these problems?

Comment: C# doesn't have anything named `FileOpenDialog`, but it does have a `OpenFileDialog`

Answer (score 0):

to get the fileDialog running, you need to copy ExplorerFrame.dll from a running windows 10 system. The file is located in system32 folder. keep an eye on the architecture.

You need to add the following registry modification to your WinPE-registry, too. This helped me out with the same issue several months ago. Depending on your app, you'll need to install WinPE-WMI.cab, WinPE-PowerShell.cab, WinPE-NetFx.cab and their language-packs as well. These can be found in MS ADK.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SW\Classes\CLSID\{AE054212-3535-4430-83ED-D501AA6680E6}]
@="Shell Name Space ListView"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SW\Classes\CLSID\{AE054212-3535-4430-83ED-D501AA6680E6}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,65,00,78,00,\
  70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,66,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,65,00,2e,00,64,\
  00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
```